# Send value from controller to another controller in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have two method in different controller class

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/addHari")
public String menuAddHari(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam(value="addchkmerah",required = false)String status, Model model) throws ParseException {
    Date hariKerja = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("addharikerja"));
    java.sql.Date workDay = new java.sql.Date(hariKerja.getTime());
    String keterangan = request.getParameter("addkolomket");
    Time jamMasuk = hs.getTime(request.getParameter("addjammasuk"));
    Time jamKeluar = hs.getTime(request.getParameter("addjampulang"));
    month = request.getParameter("addBulan");
    HariKerjaModel hm = new HariKerjaModel();
    hm.setKeterangan(keterangan);
    hm.setTanggal(workDay);
    hm.setMerahBukan(status);
    hm.setJamMasuk(jamMasuk);
    hm.setJamKeluar(jamKeluar);
    hs.saveDate(hm);
    model.addAttribute("month", month);
    return "redirect:/hariKerja";
}
```

and

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/hariKerja")
public String menuHariKerja(Model model,HttpServletRequest request) {
    List<HariKerjaModel> hk = new ArrayList<>();
    String month = request.getParameter("bulansrc");
    HariKerjaController h = new HariKerjaController();
    String x=h.getMonth();
    if(month==null) { 
        String month2 = (String) model.getAttribute("month");
    }
    hk = hs.readHariKerja(month);
    model.addAttribute("ListHariKerjaModel", hk);
    model.addAttribute("valueSelected",month);
    return "hariKerja";
}
```

how to pass value variable "month" in method "menuAddHari" to variable "month2" in method "menuHariKerja" ?

Comment: Could you briefly explain the your requirement or issue.

Comment: i only want pass value from method in one controller class to another method in another controller class.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement while redirect your request with path or query or body containing entity or fields which are url-form-encoded.

```
return StringBuffer("redirect:/your/other/controller/method/")
     .append(param1).append("/").append(param2);
```

And you will be able to handle the request in your other controller with :

```
@GetMapping(value="/your/other/controller/method/{param1}/{param2}")
public String otherMethodInOtherController(@PathVariable("paramName1") String param1, @PathVariable("paramName2") String param2) {
     // your 2sd controller code here...
     return "your-view-name";
}
```

Of course, if you have many parameters to send, it will be better to set a ResponseEntity with `BodyInserters` inside the body of your request before to send it to your 2sd controller.

And don't forget not to use GET methods to forward sensitive user|system datas.